# Vue 3 + pinia, do not update template after change states value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pinia

I use Vue3 + Pinia as store.

My Pinia file is:

```
export const useCounterStore = defineStore ({
  id: 'statusData', 
  state: () => ({
    test1: 25, 
    test2: 75
  })
})
```

and template I use:

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{ store.test1 }} {{ store.test2 }} 
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
  import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia';
  import { useCounterStore } from '@/stores/statusData';
  const store = useCounterStore();

  const { test1, test2 } = storeToRefs(store);
</script>
```

If I manually change the value in 'statusData.js' file, he value is not changed in the template. After reload browser.

Any idea where is error, please?

Comment: It's unclear what happens in your case. "If I manually change the value" - by editing the file? "After reload browser" - what's the meaning of this sentence? Does it mean that it's changed when reloading or not changed? If this is the case, it's specific to your setup and the way HMR works there, not anything else

Comment: @EstusFlask Yes, manually change file statusData.js and save it. The value is not changed (in the viewer). When I reload the browser (e.g. with the f5 key), the value will change to the correct one.

Comment: See https://pinia.vuejs.org/cookbook/hot-module-replacement.html . It's incorrect to ask the question irrelevant to your setup

Answer (score 0):

Keeping aside HMR, it is important to remember that the store AND your templates are on the server side. When you visit a Vue page, Vue "magically" generates HTML content with the values in your store.

The reason why, say template changes, are visible without refresh is thanks to HMR. Without HMR (*I think* there is a way to disable. Not sure) you'll run in to same problem.

Point is: HMR is enabled for templates not Pinia. Hence, your Pinia changes are only visible on refresh. Unless of course you enable HMR for Pinia too.